# Detect if vpn service is on or not problem

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie, jsonparser, android-vpn-service

I'm facing problem with some devices like some android box or Huawei Phones 
I need to protect my app  if user use packet  monitor app what I did is if user  has  a vpn active on their device  don't request  jsonparse 
but some devices even if vpn is not active jsonparse not run .

Here is my code

```
public static boolean isVpnConnectionActive() {
        List<String> networks = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())) {
                if (networkInterface.isUp()) {
                    networks.add(networkInterface.getName());
                }if (networkInterface.getName().contains("tun0")||  networkInterface.getName().contains("ppp0")) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        }
        return networks.contains("tun0");


    }
```

I request jsonParse on start and on create to avoid user from activating  VPN after launching my app

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (isVpnConnectionActive()) {



        }else { jsonParse();}}
```

I request for json parse by this way

```
    private void jsonParse() {

        final String url = "http://example.dns.net/json.php";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("employees");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String Urlx = employee.getString("urlx");
                                String Urlc = employee.getString("urlc");
                                String Urlb = employee.getString("urlb");
                                String TextBar = employee.getString("TextBar");


    DFG_1 = Urlx;
    DFG_2 = Urlc;
    DFG_3 = Urlb;
    Text_Bar = TextBar;
    text2.setText(TextBar);


}


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }


        });
        mQueue.add(request);

    }
```

why android pie and some devices isn't work with this way  ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you just don't use `NetworkCapabilities#hasTransport`, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#hasTransport(int)?

Using this you can check if a "network uses a VPN transport" using `TRANSPORT_VPN`.